# Google Map api  v3 - IE7 - main.js error - invalid argument (javascript)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, internet-explorer-7

http://bit.ly/xkHPnU

I've looked at all of the timing issues, and I can't seem to resolve this error. Occurs in IE7 and compatibility modes as a warn-on error.

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; Tablet PC 2.0)
Timestamp: Fri, 2 Mar 2012 21:58:06 UTC


Message: Invalid argument.
Line: 27
Char: 56
Code: 0
URI: http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/7/12/main.js
```

Need another set of eyes on it.

Thanks.

Comment: So, did you try what I explained in my answer?

Comment: @Cheery - see below - interesting issue, but a resolved interesting issue. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem appears at line 27, here: `e.minWidth=W(d)`. The result of `W(d)` is equal to '-12px' and IE does not want to set negative value to the minWidth attribute.

Debugging further I can see that this code is related to the rendering of the map controls. Moreover, the problem have place only for the switch-button between Map/Satellite views (value of `c` variable is "roadmap"). Also it looks like the code is executed by triggered `onchange` event, which might be connected to the tabs over the map. As a test I removed those tabs with a simple rule in Proxomitron and that error did not appear any more.

So, try to place those tabs in such location or way (for example with position for the parent div set to relative and the parent of tabs with absolute position and negative value of the `top` css attribute) that the part under them will not change size during their initialization (tabs script applied to them) or initialize your google map after their rendering (set some delay).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had been looking at this issue way too long. Odd issue -  in the mapOptions, I had left `mapTypeControlOptions:` blank and it was defaulting to the horizontal bar, which was throwing the error. But by explicitly declaring the `mapTypeControlOptions:`, it fixed the issue.

Comment: @Jason  This one of the typical problems with APIs :) When something is skipped or omitted it could lead to an error. But you have so much js code, that I decided to dig into the reason and not to check some missing parameters. But yes, the problem happened due to change  of the map size during the map initialization.

Answer (score 3):

setting like this

```
mapTypeControl:true, 
mapTypeControlOptions: { 
    style: window.google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU 
}
```

will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

this problem is not resolved with the given solution.

I am using two google map and using the same jquery-1.4.1.min.js file.
But when i ma running individual then it is running.
But when using two map. then 
e.minWidth=x(D)  coming with -12px values as the same stackoverflow problem .
So please provide me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem in IE8. when map is open and open debug mode in IE popup Invalid Argument will be appear

I solved by add "mapTypeControl" and "mapTypeControlOptions" like answer of **user2884829**

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    zoom: 19,
    center: latLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
         style: window.google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
    }
});
```