# I'm getting Invalid argument error when loading google maps in IE

Tags: google-maps

```
Message: Invalid argument.
Line: 26
Char: 56
Code: 0
URI: http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/9/13/main.js
```

I went through the solutions in Stack Exchange found some thing relevant at 
[Google Map api  v3 - IE7 - main.js error - invalid argument (javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540790/google-map-api-v3-ie7-main-js-error-invalid-argument-javascript)

and tried to remove the div for test purpose through jQuery like below

```
$(".gmnoprint").children().remove();
$(".gmnoprint").empty();
$('.gmnoprint').find("div").slice(1,2).hide().remove();
$('.gmnoprint').find("div").hide().remove();
$(".gmnoprint").children("div:lt(1)").remove();
$('.gmnoprint div:nth-child(1)').remove();
$(".gmnoprint").first().remove();
```

but no options has worked.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem for IE7/8 (didn't try IE6, IE9 worked well), same line and column and same maps api file version.

I figured out that this happened (at least for me) whenever map should be re-rendered on the same page (async approach), and solution was to always remove map node from DOM just before trying to re-render map again, with e.g:

```
 $('#MAP_CONTAINER_ID_HERE').children().remove();
```

with jQuery (or equivalent with native js),

Also, sometimes the problem may be in an unfinished job from the previous map rendering (assuming that we're discussing issue with maps that are re-rendered on the same page), and IEs<9 seem to be fragile when redrawing over unfinished maps.

That said - maybe you could check another thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8175425/invalid-argument-error-in-ie7-jquery-tabs-and-google-map) dealing with what I just described if removal of nodes representing previous map rendering didn't help.

Finally - if you're experiencing this bug with no map re-rendering then you're probably running into issues with improperly created options or something similar, it would be much easier to respond if some code snippet or at least scenario is given.